# how do I lock my BottomNavigationView when I make a request to my backend?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to block my  BottomNavigationView when I make a request to the backend so that the user can not move between fragments but ends up closing the application because it does not finish a request and starts another, work of the same activity -> 4 fragments

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to disable the click on BottomNavigationView

```
 bottomView.setEnabled(false); 
    bottomView.setFocusable(false); 
    bottomView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    bottomView.setClickable(false); 
    bottomView.setContextClickable(false);
    bottomView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

And you can enable it back again when you want them to be active.

```
 bottomView.setEnabled(true); 
    bottomView.setFocusable(true); 
    bottomView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    bottomView.setClickable(true); 
    bottomView.setContextClickable(true);
    bottomView.setOnClickListener(this);
```